# T-test for percentages

Tags: t-test, percentage

I have data from 50 different English second language classes. Each class I have a percentage of students that passed Test A before the language program and Test A again after the program concluded. E.g., Class 1 = 50% students passed Test A pre language program and 65% passed Test A post language program.

Can I do a paired t-test to see if the language program improved the class average? It seems weird to me use percentages as values for a participant (i.e., in this case a class). Though I don't understand statistics well enough to figure out if my feeling is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to partially disagree with @ToddD . With the data you have, a paired *t* test may be a viable approach.  I think you should calculate the difference for each school, and take a look at the histogram of these differences.  If the distribution is relatively normalish (that is, not super skewed), the *t* test should be reliable. If these differences have some very non-normal distribution, you might use (paired) Wilcoxon signed-rank test.  It will test a different hypothesis than the *t* test, but it is a nonparametric test to determine if there is a consistent trend for the post- being higher than the pre-.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the paired t-test is not ideal if pass/fail data is all you have. If you are testing the same group twice and only have pass/fail status, look at McNemar’s change test. If you have actual scores, which is preferable, the paired t-test is a good choice.

Comment: One complication is that there are several tests nested within each class.  So a simple McNemar or *t* test on the scores won't capture this. If the OP has scores from each test, or pass/fail for each test, you'd probably what to have a hierarchical or nested model that associates each score with its school.  This might be a mixed-effects logistic regression or mixed-effects gaussian (?) model.  But I suspect OP is looking for a simpler approach.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the distribution of your data. Percentages as proportions tend to be distributed differently than other continuous data, partially because they're compacted between the values of 0 and 1.

Like Sal said, it would be appropriate to use the paired t-test. However, in the event of broken normality, avoid non-parametric tests at all costs. There are many data transformations available that do not ruin literal interpretation of your test/model like non-parametric tests do. I've found that logit transformations are often successful in fixing your distribution when using proportions and can still be interpreted in terms of the original data. [This link](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/logit-transformation/) explains the concept and reasoning of a logit transformation pretty well.

If your distribution is relatively normal, it is certainly okay to go ahead and run the paired t-test.